# Upgrade brother printer firmware

Tags: windows-8, usb, printer, firmware

I'm trying to upgrade my brother firmware that is connected to my PC via USB but the software tells me there is a connection error:

[image]

So I checked my printer software and I can print/scan do whatever I want, so there is no real problem with connecting to the printer. 
I went over to my printer properties and tried to configure my port which was set to USB but got this message:

[image]

Is this normal for USB? There might be a configuration problem with my port but I cannot seem to figure out how to fix this. Might you guys have any ideas what could be wrong besides the software just being crap?

Thanks!

Comment: The printer is working. the error message simply states it can not update the printer due to a connection error. Drivers just came out for windows 8 so it should be fine, and the reason I want it upgraded is because it has print quality improvements and fixes a bug with ink cartidge measurements.

Comment: I would contact `Brother` and find out if their firmware application supports Windows 8.